# Unable to use custom Componets in AdminBro

Tags: node.js, express

I am using admin-bro with express js and everything seemed to me be working fine until I tried to add custom component to change an input field of a resource. Following is the code I am using.

**EditLogoField.jsx**

```
const React = require('react');

class EditLogoField extends React.PureComponent {
   render() {
     return (
       <input type='file'/>
     );
   }
}
 module.exports = EditLogoField;
```

I am trying to use it like this

```
const AdminBro = require('admin-bro');

module.exports = {
  properties: {
    logo: {
      type: 'string',
      isVisible: {
        list: false,
        edit: true,
        filter: false,
        show: true,
      },
      components: {
        edit: AdminBro.bundle('../components/serviceProviderCompany/EditLogoField')
      }
    },
  },
};
```

All I get is this

[image]

Comment: try to remove .adminbro folder and relaunch the app

Comment: move project into a folder that doesn't have a " . " (dot) symbol in its path.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Spent whole day trying to solve it.
Build failed on both Windows and Ubuntu systems.
My path to the project folder had a '.' symbol in it 'C:\.code\Projects' which
also caused recently some issues with Unity project.

**Solution:**

```
move project into a folder that doesn't have a '.' symbol in its path.
```